# Skypeforlinux official ppa to Ubuntu doesn't have a valid keyword

Tags: apt, ppa, skype

I use Ubuntu-Studio 20.04.2 LTS.

Since a while (2 months, aprox.), I get a "not valid key from Skypeforlinux ppa" message, each time I perform a system update.

Is it some personal mistake?

How can I get the valid keyword to that ppa?

Is it something out of my control? ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. "Key" refers an expired cryptographic key used to sign the package, not a "keyword".
2. That PPA is deprecated (that's why the key is expired). Use [the Snap](https://snapcraft.io/skype) instead.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation!!!